# Is it possible to perform the original action of a mapped key without knowing the key a priori?

Tags: key-bindings

Consider the following function and mapping.

```
function! DoMagic()
    if s:isActive
       echom "Performing magic!"
    else
       " Perform default action of whatever key was mapped to this function
    endif
endfunction

map F :call DoMagic()<CR>
```

Is there a magic command that tells vim to pretend the mapping never happened  if some condition is not true?

Answer (score 2):

Two patterns come to mind:

```
nnoremap <expr> F MyExprFunc('F')
nnoremap F :call MyFunc('F')<CR>
```

The function has to know what key is mapped to it, so it can do the appropriate thing.

Then:

```
function MyExprFunc(key)
  if blah blah
    return a:key
  else
    return magic_key_sequence
  endif
endfunction

function MyFunc(key)
  if blah blah
    exec printf("normal! %s", a:key)
  else
    " Do some magic
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: I think i accidentally inverted the conditional, but the intent should be clear

Answer (score 2):

The generic way to do this is to use the `:norm! <key>[<key>]` command. The bang (`!`) is important, it will execute the given keys as normal commands as they are not mapped.

Another more low-level alternative is to make use of the `feedkeys()` function, that allows to insert keys into the typeahead buffer and allows to define whether mappings should apply or not (among others). See the documentation: [:h :norm!](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:norm) and [:h feedkeys()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#feedkeys())